# How to use Task.WhenAny and implement retry

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a solution that creates multiple I/O based tasks and I'm using `Task.WhenAny()` to manage these tasks. But often many of the tasks will fail due to network issue or request throttling etc.

I can't seem to find a solution that enables me to successfully retry failed tasks when using a `Task.WhenAny()` approach.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<MyType>>();
foreach(var item in someCollection)
{
   task.Add(GetSomethingAsync());
}
while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
   var child = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
   tasks.Remove(child);
   ???
}
```

So the above structure works for completing tasks, but I haven't found a way to handle and retry failing tasks. The `await Task.WhenAny` throws an `AggregateException` rather than allowing me to inspect a task status. When In the exception handler I no longer have any way to retry the failed task.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the difference between your tasks? Currently it looks like you have list of equal tasks. Maybe you are passing to `GetSomethingAsync()` some parameters which are different?

Comment: @Sergey, yes I'm passing a unique parameter to GetSomethingAsync which I'd need to be able to reference when retrying s task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it would be easier to retry *within* the tasks, and then replace the `Task.WhenAny`-in-a-loop antipattern with `Task.WhenAll`

E.g., using [`Polly`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly):

```
var tasks = new List<Task<MyType>>();
var policy = ...; // See Polly documentation
foreach(var item in someCollection)
  tasks.Add(policy.ExecuteAsync(() => GetSomethingAsync()));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

or, more succinctly:

```
var policy = ...; // See Polly documentation
var tasks = someCollection.Select(item => policy.ExecuteAsync(() => GetSomethingAsync()));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: thanks @Stephen, I'll try it out. I had dabbled with Polly for this but was still using the `await Task.WhenAny` pattern which didn't lead anywhere.

Comment: @macon: No, it's just awkward. There's always a cleaner solution than having `Task.WhenAny` removing tasks as they complete (eventually waiting for them all to complete).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) library for some reason, you could use the `Retry` method below. It accepts a task factory, and keeps creating and then awaiting a task until it completes successfully, or the `maxAttempts` have been reached:

```
public static async Task<TResult> Retry<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> taskFactory,
    int maxAttempts)
{
    int failedAttempts = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Task<TResult> task = taskFactory();
            return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch
        {
            failedAttempts++;
            if (failedAttempts >= maxAttempts) throw;
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use this method to download (for example) some web pages.

```
string[] urls =
{
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "https://superuser.com",
    //"https://no-such.url",
};
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var tasks = urls.Select(url => Retry(async () =>
{
    return (Url: url, Html: await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
}, maxAttempts: 5));

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Url: {result.Url}, {result.Html.Length:#,0} chars");
}
```

Output:

```
Url: https://stackoverflow.com, 112,276 chars  
Url: https://superuser.com, 122,784 chars
```

If you uncomment the third url then instead of these results an `HttpRequestException` will be thrown, after five failed attempts.

The [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) method will wait for the completion of all tasks before propagating the error. In case it is preferable to report the error as soon as possible, you can find solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313252/how-can-i-await-an-array-of-tasks-and-stop-waiting-on-first-exception) question.