# Retry Failed Tasks in C#.Net -WhenAll Async

Tags: c#, async-await

How can I retry the failed `Task`.  Below executes tasks asynchronously. If one or many tasks failed I would like to retry the failed tasks for 3 times before setting the task as failed.

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (!tasks.Any(a => a.Result == false))
{
   result = true;
}
else 
{
   // Retry
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about moving the retry logic into the task itself? As it stands you are waiting for every task to complete, then looking for false, then planning to try again, which could extend overall run time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Task.WhenAny and implement retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763982/how-to-use-task-whenany-and-implement-retry)

Comment: @devNull Was just about to recommend [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#handing-return-values-and-policytresult) if the retry logic couldn't be moved into the task itself. Probably the cleanest way to implement this.

Comment: I think Polly is a better option.

Comment: I just added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763982/how-to-use-task-whenany-and-implement-retry/60555163#60555163) to the duplicate question.