# Catching exceptions in Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

A class has async method `MonitorAsync()`, which starts a long-running parallel operation. I have a collection of these `monitors`; these are all kicked off as follows:

```
    internal async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var tasks = monitors.Select((p) => p.Value.MonitorAsync());
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

If a `monitor` falls over, I need to know (basically I will run it up again). I've looked into `ContinueWith` and so on but when running a bunch of async tasks in parallel, how can I ensure I definitely know when one ends?

For context, `RunAsync` is basically the core of my application.

Comment: Related: [How to use Task.WhenAny and implement retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763982/how-to-use-task-whenany-and-implement-retry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a monitor falls over, I need to know (basically I will run it up again).

The easiest way to do this is to define this logic in a separate method:

```
internal async Task RunAsync()
{
  var tasks = monitors.Select(p => MonitorAndRestart(p));
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

  async Task MonitorAndRestart(P p)
  {
    while (true)
    {
      try { await p.Value.MonitorAsync(); }
      catch { ... }
      p.Restart();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to know when one ends (and that does not affect the others), ContinueWith()  could be the way.

Alternatively, how about WaitAny in a loop?

```
while(anyTaskUnfinished){
    await Task.WaitAny(tasks);
}
//Stuff you do after WhenAll() comes here
```

I am uncertain if you have to remove already finished Tasks. Or if it waits for any newly finishing.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

> If you do not want to call the Task.Wait method to wait for a task's completion, you can also retrieve the AggregateException exception from the task's Exception property

```cs
internal async Task RunAsync()
{
    var tasks = monitors.Select((p) => p.Value.MonitorAsync());
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks.Where(x => x.IsFaulted))
        foreach (var exception in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [Exception handling (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)

Comment: This solution will delay the restarting of a failed monitor until all other monitors have been completed. Which is probably too late.