# How to make sure a task is completed in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I need to execute a task like this (I do not have control of that task's source code)

```
public Task DoSomething()
```

Sometimes that task is failed to complete. And this method will not raise any exception. In this case, I want to execute that task again until it is completed.
In order to do so, I try like this :

```
Task task;
do {
    task = Task.Run(async () => await DoSomething();
    await Task.Delay(300);
}
while (!task.IsCompleted);
```

Is it correct ? Is there any better way ?

Comment: Use the `await` operator.

Comment: No, this is definitely not correct, you start a new task when the previous one didn't finish in 300 ms.

Comment: > “Is it correct?” - **no**

Comment: There's a huge difference between "hasn't completed yet" and "faulted" - right now, you could be starting hundreds of `DoSomething()` calls *in parallel* (one new one every 300ms), which sounds like a way to get catastrophically worse and worse performance, and more long-running operations. What is `DoSomething()` here?

Comment: Try: `await DoSomething();`

Comment: You can/should replace all your code shown with this one line: `await DoSomething();`. That will suspend execution until the Task returned by DoSomething completes, an error will result in an Exception being thrown.

Comment: You really should make sure, if you are going to retry, you have a strategy for eventually admitting defeat. Sometimes that intermittent failure isn't so intermittent and your code would just silently be retrying without anyone knowing where it's stuck.

Comment: As a side note, the `DoSomething()` is not a task. It is an asynchronous method. `Task` is what this method returns when it is invoked.

Comment: The problem is, sometimes, DoSomething has never completed. I would like to retry DoSomething until it completes once. But I don't know how to achieve it. DoSomething won't return any exception.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to use Task.WhenAny and implement retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763982/how-to-use-task-whenany-and-implement-retry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, probably, want something like this:

```
  // Trying to complete task again and again... 
  // you may want to give some number of attempt to complete, say 
  // for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= 3; ++i) {
  while (true) {
    // Let task 300 ms to completet before it'll be canceled
    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(300)) {
      try {
        await DoSomething(cts.Token);

        // Task Succeeded, break the loop
        break;
      }
      catch (TaskCanceledException) {
        // Task Cancelled, keep on looping
        ;
      }
    }
  }
```

Note, that you should have some *support* in `DoSomething`:

```
   async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken token)
```

instead of

```
   async Task DoSomething()
```

since we should know how to *cancel* it. If you **don't have**

```
   async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken token)
```

or alike signature, (with `CancellationToken`), the bitter truth is that you **can't cancel**. You can try wait (and forget the task if it's not completed):

```
   // Since we are going to forget running tasks, let's
   // restrict number of attempts 
   for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= 3; ++attempt) {
     Task task = DoSomething();

     if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(300)) == task) {
       // task has been completed before timeout
       break;
     } 

     // we forget task (alas, we can't cancel it) and try again
   }
```

Comment: I dont understand this: the DoSomething() doesn't accept any parameter and the OP says he has no control over its source code. In your answer's code example, you put a cancelation token into DoSomething()

Comment: @user2190492: Thank you! So the problem is if there is `async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken token)` overload and if it is we can use the cancellation; if not - all we can do it to *forget* the previous attempt, and run `DoSomething()` once again

Comment: Thanks for this comment. that task can't cancel. But I will use "try wait and forget" way you post.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke async method directly with `await`.

In case of error an exception should be throw.

Your code should become something like this.

```cs
bool repeat = false;
do {
    try 
    { 
        await DoSomething(); 
        repeat = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        repeat = true;
    }
    if (repeat)
        await Task.Delay(300); 
}
while (repeat); // better with some kind of timeout or attempts counter...
```

Moreover,  `IsCompleted`  include also `Faulted` and `Cancelled`. If you want to use your approach you need to use new property `IsCompletedSuccessfully` or exclude `IsFault` and `IsCancelled` (if you use an old .NET fwk).

Comment: No exception will e thrown in DoSomething(), I have tried this way already. I can not edit source code of DoSomething() to throw exception. So I can not use this way.