# Repeat a specific requests when failing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a couple of web-requests that I want to perform and that are independent. So I put all these tasks into a loop and use `WhenAll` to just `await` when all tasks finished.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var component in doc.Descendants("component"))
{
    tasks.Add(DoSomething());            
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

where `DoSomething` is this:

```
async Task DoSomething() => await client.PerformRequest();
```

Now I have a problem as the service is quite unstable and many of these requests fail. So I just want to re-send them for a configurable amount, say five times. So when one request fails, just retry it. How can I do that?

I've tried this, however that doesn't return a `Task` anymore and therefor there's no way to use `Task.WhenAll`.

```
async void DoSomething()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            await client1.PerformRequest();
            break;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("retrying");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be handled by Polly retry policies at the HttpClient level and can be easily configured with `AddHttpClient`. Check [Implement HTTP call retries with exponential backoff with IHttpClientFactory and Polly policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly)

Comment: You can also look into using a tool that handles all these retries for you. Polly is excellent, and free, and I highly recommend it https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: You can use Polly by itself to retry any operation but HttpClient integration make retries almost transparent and can handle problems like server throttling (429) by inspecting failure responses directly

Comment: sh**... I forgot t mention that this is no HTTP- but a SOAP-request :|

Comment: Related: [How to use Task.WhenAny and implement retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763982/how-to-use-task-whenany-and-implement-retry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry).

In the example polly is retrying 3 times before throwing the exception finally. In the documentation link above you can find several examples to retry, circuit break, etc.

```cs
   await Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .RetryAsync(3, onRetry: (exception, retryCount, context) =>
        {
            // Do your logging or setup for retries here
            Console.WriteLine($"Retry Count: {retryCount}");
        }).ExecuteAsync(async () => {
            
            // Call your SOAP service here
            await CallSoapService();
        });
```

Working example [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8EGXK3)

Comment: that seems to work. Thank you. You forgot the `Task.WhenAll`-thing, though I was able to to apply that myself.